# on changing the select option for second time

Tags: javascript, forms, drop-down-menu

i am creating a webpage using html,php and javascript.
i have used script for select option. The problem i am encountering on executing the code is that the first input field doesn't disappear on selecting the option again. instead i get the second input box and first input box as well. i.e. i get both even if i use if else condition.

```js
var fil = document.getElementById("filter");
fil.onchange = function filteron() {
  var filtertag = document.getElementById("filter");
  var tag = filtertag.options[filtertag.selectedIndex].value;
  var searchbox = document.createElement("input");
  var filter = document.getElementById("criteriain");
  searchbox.setAttribute("id", "criteria");
  if (tag === 'ed') {
    searchbox.setAttribute("type", "date");
    searchbox.setAttribute("name", "searchin");
  } else if (tag === 'gw') {
    searchbox.setAttribute("type", "number");
    searchbox.setAttribute("name", "searchin");
  }
  filter.appendChild(searchbox);

};
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <label for="filter" id="filterin">Filter by</label>
  <select id="filter" size="1" name="filter" onchange="filteron()">
                <option value='slno' >Sl No</option>
                <option value='ed' >Entry Date</option>
                <option value='lot' >Lot No</option>
                <option value='par' >Party</option>
                <option value='var' >Variety</option>
                <option value='cst' >Current status</option>
                <option value='gw' >Gray width</option>
            </select>
  <br/>

  <label for='criteria' id='criteriain'>Search for</label>
```

Comment: You do not remove old elements. So they stay. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

It is because irrespective of your selection you are creating a new element every time and only changing the type in if/else block for new element.

```js
var fil = document.getElementById("filter");
fil.onchange = function filteron() {
  var filtertag = document.getElementById("filter");
  var tag = filtertag.options[filtertag.selectedIndex].value;
  var searchbox = document.getElementById("criteria");
  var filter = document.getElementById("criteriain");
  if(undefined === searchbox || null === searchbox) {
    searchbox = document.createElement("input");
    searchbox.setAttribute("id", "criteria");
  }
  
  if (tag === 'ed') {
    searchbox.setAttribute("type", "date");
    searchbox.setAttribute("name", "searchin");
  } else if (tag === 'gw') {
    searchbox.setAttribute("type", "number");
    searchbox.setAttribute("name", "searchin");
  }
  filter.appendChild(searchbox);

};
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <label for="filter" id="filterin">Filter by</label>
  <select id="filter" size="1" name="filter" onchange="filteron()">
                <option value='slno' >Sl No</option>
                <option value='ed' >Entry Date</option>
                <option value='lot' >Lot No</option>
                <option value='par' >Party</option>
                <option value='var' >Variety</option>
                <option value='cst' >Current status</option>
                <option value='gw' >Gray width</option>
            </select>
  <br/>

  <label for='criteria' id='criteriain'>Search for</label>
```

Comment: I have edited my code. The problem was everything was set to visible mode. So i have just used if else statement with hidden tag incorporated using javascript